# Heroku app crashes immediately upon startup, works fine locally, tried everything I can think of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave, cloudinary

**EDIT:** so I copied my files to a new directory, created a new git repo, created a new heroku app, pushed to the new heroku app, configured a few heroku environment variables, and . . . everything works fine now. Same exact code. Anyone have any clue as to what causes a Heroku app to become corrupted like this? If this happened when we were in production we would be in serious trouble.

I added CarrierWave and Cloudinary to my app, works great locally, crashes on Heroku.

Oddly it worked on a later heroku push (after making a trivial change), and rolling back to that known working release still doesn't fix things (still crashes). Heroku support is looking at it but is slow to respond (their suggestions so far have not worked). Here is a link to the gist of the Heroku logfile:

https://gist.github.com/gosuto/5278659

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: That is enormous and unreadable.  Please cut it back and format it properly.  If you think all of that is important, put it in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and post an excerpt/summary here using the [Stack Overflow markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: edited (added link to gist), my bad, 48 hours into this issue and my eyes are starting to cross

Comment: Looks like you have an issue with an association defined in line 15 of app/models/building_tour.rb

Comment: Yeah, wasn't a problem with the code (that line was just a belongs_to statement) . . . works fine on a new heroku app, identical code (I just copied all the code to a new directory and then created a new git repo and heroku app). Dyno must have been "broken". Waiting on feedback from Heroku. Bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a NewRelic issue. I had newrelic_rpm in my Gemfile and apparently that conflicts with either CarrierWave or Cloudinary. I removed newrelic_rpm from my Gemfile and all is right from the world.

I am waiting on word back from Heroku and NewRelic on whether or not I can specify a specific version of newrelic_rpm to avoid this issue. Once I get more details I will update this answer.

Ben

Comment: Having what seems to be exact same problem

Comment: Sadly I don't have any more details yet. I added newrelic_rpm back to the new version of my app and all seems to be ok. Bizarre.